# Why inserting `format` function inside a `dolist` expression does not work in Common Lisp?

Tags: printing, format, iteration, common-lisp

I am using SBCL, Eamcs, and Slime. Using the `print` function, I can do:

```lisp
CL-USER> (dolist (item '(1 2 3))
           (print item))
1 
2 
3 
NIL
```

In addition, `format` function works for single elements:

```lisp
CL-USER> (format nil "~a" 1)
"1"
```

Why the following insertion of `format` function inside `dolist` does not work?

```lisp
CL-USER> (dolist (item '(1 2 3))
           (format nil "~a" item))
NIL
```

I was expecting to see all elements of the list processed by the `format` function.

Thanks

Comment: your `(FORMAT NIL ...)`does no output at all. Your DOLIST always returns NIL and does no output itself. Why would you expect to see any output?

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting because the expression is properly evaluated out of the `do-list` with the following call: `CL-USER> (format nil "~a" 1)` and the result: `"1"`

Comment: The REPL works fine printing the result of the FORMAT expression. FORMAT does no output there. Check the documentation of FORMAT. The result of your DOLIST is NIL and that is successfully printed by the REPL.

Comment: see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_c.htm. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is that the first argument to `format` denotes a *destination* for the formatted output.  It may be one of four things:

- a stream, to which output goes;
- `t` which denotes the value of the `*standard-output*` stream;
- `nil` which causes `format` to *return* the formatted output rather than print it;
- or a string with a fill pointer, which will append the output to the string at the fill pointer.

So `(format nil ...)` does not print anything: it *returns* something.

Answer (score 2):

Here DOLIST prints a list of numbers and returns NIL (because by default DOLIST returns NIL).

```lisp
(dolist (item '(1 2 3))
    (print item))
```

`format nil …` creates a string. But DOLIST returns NIL, so you see nothing.

You can `format t …` to standard output, you can return values with DOLIST with `return`, but it returns and exits the loop (so it won't process every element).

You can use LOOP with `collect` to return something:

```lisp
(loop for item in '(1 2 3)
    collect (format nil "~a" item))
("1" "2" "3")
```

using `do` wouldn't print nor return anything either.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to do a minor tweak on the format function to have the same result:

```lisp
CL-USER> (dolist (item '(1 2 3))
           (format t "~a ~%" item))
1 
2 
3 
NIL
```

Comment: FORMAT expects for printing a stream and T is standing for the `*standard-output*` stream.